# How do I integrate Stripe and Parse with Webhooks?

Tags: parse-platform, webhooks

I'm building a chrome extension, with Parse as my backend, and Stripe as my credit card processor.

I've looked at the Cloud Modules on Parse  - https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#stripe - but it wasn't great at explaining how I can connect the two.

Anyone have experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Far too broad of a question. If there are Parse forums, try there.